# Icon overlay issue with Python

Tags: python, windows, shell, com, py2exe

I found some examples and topics on this forum about the way to implement an icon overlay handler with Python 2.7 & the win32com package but it does not work for me and I don't understand why.

I create the DLL and I have no error when I register it. I have also tried directly with the script but it's the same. It's like the class is never called.

Here is the code:

```
import win32traceutil

from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import pythoncom
import winerror
import os

REG_PATH =r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers'
REG_KEY = "GdIconOverlayTest"

class GdClass:
    _reg_clsid_='{512AE200-F075-41E6-97DD-48ECA4311F2E}'
    _reg_progid_='GD.TestServer'
    _reg_desc_='gd desc'
    _public_methods_ = ['GetOverlayInfo','GetPriority','IsMemberOf']
    _com_interfaces_=[shell.IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def GetOverlayInfo(self):
        return (os.path.abspath(r'C:\icons\test.ico'), 0, shellcon.ISIOI_ICONFILE)

    def GetPriority(self):
        return 0

    def IsMemberOf(self, fname, attributes):
        print('ismemberOf', fname, os.path.basename(fname))
        if os.path.basename(fname) == "hello.text":
            return winerror.S_OK
        return winerror.E_FAIL

def DllRegisterServer():
    print "Registering %s" % REG_KEY
    import _winreg
    key = _winreg.CreateKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH)
    subkey = _winreg.CreateKey(key, GdClass._reg_progid_)
    _winreg.SetValueEx(subkey, None, 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, GdClass._reg_clsid_)
    print "Registration complete: %s" % GdClass._reg_desc_

def DllUnregisterServer():
    print "Unregistering %s" % REG_KEY
    import _winreg
    try:
        key = _winreg.DeleteKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"%s\%s" % (REG_PATH, GdClass._reg_progid_))
    except WindowsError, details:
        import errno
        if details.errno != errno.ENOENT:
            raise
    print "Unregistration complete: %s" % GdClass._reg_desc_

if __name__=='__main__':
    from win32com.server import register
    register.UseCommandLine(GdClass,
                            finalize_register = DllRegisterServer,
                            finalize_unregister = DllUnregisterServer)
```

---

Hi and thanks for your answer.
I have tested with a log file and also win32traceutil. The registration/unregitration messages are logged. The registry entries are also created under:

1/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\GD.TestServer 
2/ HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved
3/ directly under class root.

I have also added some logs inside the methods getOverlayInfo, GetPriority and isMemberOf but I can't see a trace when I browse through the explorer.

My configuration is:
Python 2.7
pywin32-214.win32-py2.7.exe
Windows XP SP 2

You can download all the code [here](http://kobiarts.free.fr/python/iconoverlay.zip):

Comment: Write entries to a log file in order to see which functions are actually called (if at all). Calls to `DllRegisterServer` are especially of interest here.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. i guess something was badly initialized but now it works.

My wish is to make something like the dropBox service.

i need to be able to update the icon of a given file according to its upload status. I will create a class for each state (uploading, uploaded, failed) that will implements the IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier interface. But then...

should i write the list of files that are currently uploading/failed_to_upload in local files the check the presence of each file into the isMemberOf method to determine the good icon to display? Is it the best way to do that or it would be better for instance to store all the file path inside a key in the registry?

Thanks for your help.