# Have icon overlays persist after machine restart in Python

Tags: python, windows, com, overlay

So, thanks to the Tim Golden [guide](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-my-own-icon-overlays.html) and other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775020/icon-overlay-issue-with-python#) here I have a script that will show overlays on files and folders based on their "state" similar to Tortoise SVN or Dropbox.

My problem is that once I restart the explorer.exe process or the OS itself and open explorer there are no longer any overlays.

My first thought:

- Have the service that actually manages file state detect that no requests have come in and just re-register the overlay handler

The problem here is that registration requires elevated permissions which is acceptable on initial install of the application by the end user but not every time they restart their machine.

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing here?
I have the class BaseOverlay and its children in a single .py file and register from my main app by calling this script using subprocess.

```
subprocess.check_call(script_path, shell=True)
```

Is Explorer not able to re-load the script as it is Python? Do I need to compile into a DLL or EXE? Would that change the registration process?

Here's the registration call:

```
win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(BaseOverlay)
```

Here's the class(simplified):

```
class BaseOverlay:
    _reg_clsid_ = '{8D4B1C5D-F8AC-4FDA-961F-A0143CD97C41}'
    _reg_progid_ = 'someoverlays'
    _reg_desc_ = 'Icon Overlay Handler'
    _public_methods_ = ['GetOverlayInfo', 'GetPriority', 'IsMemberOf']
    _com_interfaces_ = [shell.IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier]

    def GetOverlayInfo(self):
        return icon_path, 0, shellcon.ISIOI_ICONFILE

    def GetPriority(self):
        return 50

    def IsMemberOf(self, fname, attributes):
        return winerror.S_OK
```